# Better Approach in Downloading Image From Server to SD Card

Tags: java, php, android, json, base64

My images are stored in the document root and the image paths(strings) are saved in the database. Each item in the database is associated with one `imagePath`. The next thing is to transfer those images to the Android Sd Card.

The Dilemma:

1) I have a php script that *converts* the image file to base64, then stored in a Json Object together with the item details. After converting, the base64 string will be *converted(using java)*  into **image again** and saved it to the sd card. Also, in this approach I can easy store the images path in sqlite coz it is associated directly to an item.

```
$type = pathinfo($row["imagePath"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        // individually get each arrays
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                        {// Save Main Groups Images in SD CARD

                            byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(
                                    c.getString(TAG_IMAGE_NAME),
                                    Base64.DEFAULT);
                            Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory
                                    .decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0,
                                            decodedString.length);
}
```

---

2) The second approach, is to just directly save the image path(not being converted) to json and then
java handles the downloading of the images then saved it to sd card as well as sqlite for the image path.

```
URL url = new URL(_url);
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.connect();
InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
```

I wanted the first approach, it is cool because of many process, but I'm worried with the apps performance I think app. 2 is better. What is the efficient way of saving the files to the sd card and also making sure that the image path in the sd card is being stored in sqlite?

Comment: Use android query framework which handles db caching and it is very fast in terms of performance. jar and source code available here http://code.google.com/p/android-query/

Comment: do I need to disregard my php script and use the android query? does this lib meets my concern sir?

Comment: you have to give url of image to androidquery it will download and store to sdcard. When try to download second time from same url android query manage itself and it check in db whether image is already in sdcard then will return from sdcard not go for download.

Comment: By the way I am also, using Universal Image Loader for handling the display and caching.

Comment: I am using this framework since 2 years and have great experience with it.

Comment: That's good to know. I am afraid to use the Android Query because it is new to me, and I am quite familiar with Universal Image Loader already. Hmmmm, how about I will use Android Query just for saving the images(.jpg) in the sd card would that be okay?